# Regex for finding all uppercase words, excluding XYZ

Tags: regex

Tried using the regex `\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b` to find all uppercase words containing at least 2 uppercase letters. But there is one word that I am not interested in and it occurs too many times to skip it manually. How should I modify the regex to exclude that specific word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix your regex with a negative look ahead:

```
(?!XYZ)\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b
```

[RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/hS1dB4/1)

Could do the "at least two" more explicitely like

```
(?!XYZ)\b[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately my IDE does not seem to like `{2,}` thus hardcoding.

Comment: Yeah - as long as it does support the look ahead, you are safe. ;-)  Anything else to round it up?